# Como usar o componente SideNav da gem Materialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, materialize

Quero usar o SideNav do Materializecss, mas quando coloco ele em application.html.erb, utilizando [a documentação](http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html) as imagens não ficam no local que deveriam ficar.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Segue o código atual:
application.html.erb

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SisComSESA</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="top-nav">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <%= link_to t('.application'), root_path, class: ['brand-logo center page-title'] %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse show-on-large"><%= material_icon.menu %></a>
      </nav>

      <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
          <li><div class="user-view">
            <div class="background">
              <%= image_tag 'pav_esa.jpg' %>
            </div>
            <a href="#!user"><%= image_tag 'pav_esa.jpg', class: 'circle' %></a>
            <a href="#!name"><span class="white-text name">John Doe</span></a>
            <a href="#!email"><span class="white-text email">jdandturk@gmail.com</span></a>
          </div></li>
          <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>First Link With Icon</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">Second Link</a></li>
          <li><div class="divider"></div></li>
          <li><a class="subheader">Subheader</a></li>
          <li><a class="waves-effect" href="#!">Third Link With Waves</a></li>
        </ul>

    </header>
    <main>

        <%= yield %>

    </main>
    <footer class="page-footer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col l6 s12">
            <h5 class="white-text"><%= t('.owner') %></h5>
            <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4"><%= t('.mission') %></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col l4 offset-l2 s12">
            <h5 class="white-text">Links</h5>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="https://webmail.esa.ensino.eb.br/">
                  <%= (material_icon.mail.md_18)%> <%=  t('.email') %>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="http://www.esa.ensino.eb.br">
                  <%= (material_icon.open_in_browser.md_18)%> <%=  t('.site') %>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-copyright">
        <div class="container">
          2017
          <a class="grey-text text-lighten-4 right" href="mailto:diegobiavati@gmail.com"><%= (material_icon.report_problem.md_18)%> <%=  t('.contact')%></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

application.scss

```
@import "materialize/components/color";

// ==========================================================================
// Materialize variables
// ==========================================================================
//
// Table of Contents:
//
//  1. Colors
//  2. Badges
//  3. Buttons
//  4. Cards
//  5. Collapsible
//  6. Chips
//  7. Date + Time Picker
//  8. Dropdown
//  9. Fonts
//  10. Forms
//  11. Global
//  12. Grid
//  13. Navigation Bar
//  14. Side Navigation
//  15. Photo Slider
//  16. Spinners | Loaders
//  17. Tabs
//  18. Tables
//  19. Toasts
//  20. Typography
//  21. Footer
//  22. Flow Text
//  23. Collections
//  24. Progress Bar



// 1. Colors
// ==========================================================================

$primary-color: color("teal", "darken-4") !default;
$primary-color-light: lighten($primary-color, 15%) !default;
$primary-color-dark: darken($primary-color, 15%) !default;

$secondary-color: color("teal", "lighten-1") !default;
$success-color: color("green", "base") !default;
$error-color: color("red", "base") !default;
$link-color: color("light-blue", "darken-1") !default;


// 2. Badges
// ==========================================================================

$badge-bg-color: $secondary-color !default;
$badge-height: 22px !default;


// 3. Buttons
// ==========================================================================

// Shared styles
$button-border: none !default;
$button-background-focus: lighten($secondary-color, 4%) !default;
$button-font-size: 1rem !default;
$button-icon-font-size: 1.3rem !default;
$button-height: 36px !default;
$button-padding: 0 2rem !default;
$button-radius: 2px !default;

// Disabled styles
$button-disabled-background: #DFDFDF !default;
$button-disabled-color: #9F9F9F !default;

// Raised buttons
$button-raised-background: $secondary-color !default;
$button-raised-background-hover: lighten($button-raised-background, 5%) !default;
$button-raised-color: #fff !default;

// Large buttons
$button-large-icon-font-size: 1.6rem !default;
$button-large-height: $button-height * 1.5 !default;

// Flat buttons
$button-flat-color: #343434 !default;
$button-flat-disabled-color: lighten(#999, 10%) !default;

// Floating buttons
$button-floating-background: $secondary-color !default;
$button-floating-background-hover: $button-floating-background !default;
$button-floating-color: #fff !default;
$button-floating-size: 40px !default;
$button-floating-large-size: 56px !default;
$button-floating-radius: 50% !default;


// 4. Cards
// ==========================================================================

$card-padding: 24px !default;
$card-bg-color: #fff !default;
$card-link-color: color("orange", "accent-2") !default;
$card-link-color-light: lighten($card-link-color, 20%) !default;


// 5. Collapsible
// ==========================================================================

$collapsible-height: 3rem !default;
$collapsible-line-height: $collapsible-height !default;
$collapsible-header-color: #fff !default;
$collapsible-border-color: #ddd !default;


// 6. Chips
// ==========================================================================

$chip-bg-color: #e4e4e4 !default;
$chip-border-color: #9e9e9e !default;
$chip-selected-color: #26a69a !default;
$chip-margin: 5px !default;


// 7. Date + Time Picker
// ==========================================================================

$datepicker-display-font-size: 2.8rem;
$datepicker-weekday-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .87) !default;
$datepicker-weekday-bg: darken($secondary-color, 7%) !default;
$datepicker-date-bg: $secondary-color !default;
$datepicker-year: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7) !default;
$datepicker-focus: rgba(0,0,0, .05) !default;
$datepicker-selected: $secondary-color !default;
$datepicker-selected-outfocus: desaturate(lighten($secondary-color, 35%), 15%) !default;

$timepicker-clock-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .87) !default;
$timepicker-clock-plate-bg: #eee;


// 8. Dropdown
// ==========================================================================

$dropdown-bg-color: #fff !default;
$dropdown-hover-bg-color: #eee !default;
$dropdown-color: $secondary-color !default;
$dropdown-item-height: 50px !default;


// 9. Fonts
// ==========================================================================

$roboto-font-path: "../fonts/roboto/" !default;


// 10. Forms
// ==========================================================================

// Text Inputs + Textarea
$input-height: 3rem !default;
$input-border-color: color("grey", "base") !default;
$input-border: 1px solid $input-border-color !default;
$input-background: #fff !default;
$input-error-color: $error-color !default;
$input-success-color: $success-color !default;
$input-focus-color: $secondary-color !default;
$input-font-size: 1rem !default;
$input-margin-bottom: 20px;
$input-margin: 0 0 $input-margin-bottom 0 !default;
$input-padding: 0 !default;
$input-transition: all .3s !default;
$label-font-size: .8rem !default;
$input-disabled-color: rgba(0,0,0, .26) !default;
$input-disabled-solid-color: #BDBDBD !default;
$input-disabled-border: 1px dotted $input-disabled-color !default;
$input-invalid-border: 1px solid $input-error-color !default;
$placeholder-text-color: lighten($input-border-color, 20%) !default;

// Radio Buttons
$radio-fill-color: $secondary-color !default;
$radio-empty-color: #5a5a5a !default;
$radio-border: 2px solid $radio-fill-color !default;

// Range
$range-height: 14px !default;
$range-width: 14px !default;
$track-height: 3px !default;

// Select
$select-border: 1px solid #f2f2f2 !default;
$select-background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.90) !default;
$select-focus: 1px solid lighten($secondary-color, 47%) !default;
$select-padding: 5px !default;
$select-radius: 2px !default;
$select-disabled-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3) !default;

// Switches
$switch-bg-color: $secondary-color !default;
$switch-checked-lever-bg: desaturate(lighten($secondary-color, 25%), 25%) !default;
$switch-unchecked-bg: #F1F1F1 !default;
$switch-unchecked-lever-bg: #818181 !default;
$switch-radius: 15px !default;


// 11. Global
// ==========================================================================

// Media Query Ranges
$small-screen-up: 601px !default;
$medium-screen-up: 993px !default;
$large-screen-up: 1201px !default;
$small-screen: 600px !default;
$medium-screen: 992px !default;
$large-screen: 1200px !default;

$medium-and-up: "only screen and (min-width : #{$small-screen-up})" !default;
$large-and-up: "only screen and (min-width : #{$medium-screen-up})" !default;
$extra-large-and-up: "only screen and (min-width : #{$large-screen-up})" !default;
$small-and-down: "only screen and (max-width : #{$small-screen})" !default;
$medium-and-down: "only screen and (max-width : #{$medium-screen})" !default;
$medium-only: "only screen and (min-width : #{$small-screen-up}) and (max-width : #{$medium-screen})" !default;


// 12. Grid
// ==========================================================================

$num-cols: 12 !default;
$gutter-width: 1.5rem !default;
$element-top-margin: $gutter-width/3 !default;
$element-bottom-margin: ($gutter-width*2)/3 !default;


// 13. Navigation Bar
// ==========================================================================

$navbar-height: 64px !default;
$navbar-line-height: $navbar-height !default;
$navbar-height-mobile: 56px !default;
$navbar-line-height-mobile: $navbar-height-mobile !default;
$navbar-font-size: 1rem !default;
$navbar-font-color: #fff !default;
$navbar-brand-font-size: 2.1rem !default;

// 14. Side Navigation
// ==========================================================================

$sidenav-font-size: 14px !default;
$sidenav-font-color: rgba(0,0,0,.87) !default;
$sidenav-bg-color: #fff !default;
$sidenav-padding: 16px !default;
$sidenav-item-height: 48px !default;
$sidenav-line-height: $sidenav-item-height !default;


// 15. Photo Slider
// ==========================================================================

$slider-bg-color: color('grey', 'base') !default;
$slider-bg-color-light: color('grey', 'lighten-2') !default;
$slider-indicator-color: color('green', 'base') !default;


// 16. Spinners | Loaders
// ==========================================================================

$spinner-default-color: $secondary-color !default;


// 17. Tabs
// ==========================================================================

$tabs-underline-color: $primary-color-light !default;
$tabs-text-color: $primary-color !default;
$tabs-bg-color: #fff !default;


// 18. Tables
// ==========================================================================

$table-border-color: #d0d0d0 !default;
$table-striped-color: #f2f2f2 !default;


// 19. Toasts
// ==========================================================================

$toast-height: 48px !default;
$toast-color: #323232 !default;
$toast-text-color: #fff !default;


// 20. Typography
// ==========================================================================

$off-black: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87) !default;
// Header Styles
$h1-fontsize: 4.2rem !default;
$h2-fontsize: 3.56rem !default;
$h3-fontsize: 2.92rem !default;
$h4-fontsize: 2.28rem !default;
$h5-fontsize: 1.64rem !default;
$h6-fontsize: 1rem !default;


// 21. Footer
// ==========================================================================

$footer-bg-color: $primary-color !default;


// 22. Flow Text
// ==========================================================================

$range : $large-screen - $small-screen !default;
$intervals: 20 !default;
$interval-size: $range / $intervals !default;


// 23. Collections
// ==========================================================================

$collection-border-color: #e0e0e0 !default;
$collection-bg-color: #fff !default;
$collection-active-bg-color: $secondary-color !default;
$collection-active-color: lighten($secondary-color, 55%) !default;
$collection-hover-bg-color: #ddd !default;
$collection-link-color: $secondary-color !default;
$collection-line-height: 1.5rem !default;


// 24. Progress Bar
// ==========================================================================

$progress-bar-color: $secondary-color !default;


body {
     display: flex;
     min-height: 100vh;
     flex-direction: column;
 }
 main {
     flex: 1 0 auto;
 }

.footer-copyright {
  font-size: 14px;
}
@import "materialize";
@import "material_icons";
```

O código da aplicação está em [github](https://github.com/diegobiavati/siscomsesa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como estava usando a [Gem materialize-sass](https://github.com/mkhairi/materialize-sass) na versão 0.97.8 o erro ocorria hoje depois de atualizar para a Gem na versão 0.99 o erro deixou de ocorrer.